# How to disable input tag in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I want to disable input tag ,my demo code is

```
echo $this->Form->input('AreaMaster.GroupID', array('type'=>'select', 'div'=>'control-group', 
                    'cascadeFrom'=>'AreaMasterAreaType012',  'label'=>array('text' => 'Area Group','class'=>'control-label required'),'tabindex'=>'4', 'autoBind' => false,
                        'options'=>$dataSource, 'disabled' => 'true'));
```

I applied `'disabled' => 'true'` but it not work .
So please suggest me appropriate solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `'disabled' => 'true'` (notice the single quotes you have around `true`. This may have been the reason. I am using `CakePHP 2.3` and it's working fine however.

You can also use any of the following:

```
'disabled'
'disabled' => 'disabled'
'disabled' => true
```

So your code would look like one of these:

```
echo $this->Form->input('AreaMaster.GroupID', array('type'=>'select', 'div'=>'control-group', 
                    'cascadeFrom'=>'AreaMasterAreaType012',  'label'=>array('text' => 'Area Group','class'=>'control-label required'),'tabindex'=>'4', 'autoBind' => false,
                        'options'=>$dataSource, 'disabled'));

echo $this->Form->input('AreaMaster.GroupID', array('type'=>'select', 'div'=>'control-group', 
                    'cascadeFrom'=>'AreaMasterAreaType012',  'label'=>array('text' => 'Area Group','class'=>'control-label required'),'tabindex'=>'4', 'autoBind' => false,
                        'options'=>$dataSource, 'disabled' => 'disabled'));

echo $this->Form->input('AreaMaster.GroupID', array('type'=>'select', 'div'=>'control-group', 
                    'cascadeFrom'=>'AreaMasterAreaType012',  'label'=>array('text' => 'Area Group','class'=>'control-label required'),'tabindex'=>'4', 'autoBind' => false,
                        'options'=>$dataSource, 'disabled' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `'disabled'`

Like-

```
echo $this->Form->input('AreaMaster.GroupID', array('type'=>'select', 'div'=>'control-group', 
                    'cascadeFrom'=>'AreaMasterAreaType012',  'label'=>array('text' => 'Area Group','class'=>'control-label required'),'tabindex'=>'4', 'autoBind' => false,
                        'options'=>$dataSource, 'disabled'));
```